# Alfresco Upgrade v4.1.2 to v4.2.2.12 - Lucene full index rebuild impossible

Tags: lucene, upgrade, alfresco, reindex

I did Alfresco upgrade from v4.1.2 to v4.2.2.12. So first I did upgrade from v4.1.2 to v4.1.9.4 (to apply last patch) and then from v4.1.9.4 to v.4.2.2.12. Everything passed well in the logs and I didn't noticed any exceptions.

But when I wanted to do FULL Lucene index rebuild I end up with issue. So when I delete lucene-indexes folder, increase logging for Lucense and set index.recovery.mode=FULL and restart Alfresco, related to index rebuild, I see just following in the logs:

11:39:29,170 DEBUG [org.alfresco.repo.node.index.FullIndexRecoveryComponent] [http-bio-443-exec-17] Performing index recovery for type: FULL 
11:39:39,953 INFO [org.alfresco.repo.node.index.FullIndexRecoveryComponent] [http-bio-443-exec-17] Index recovery started: 268'330 transactions. 
11:39:43,978 INFO [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [indexTrackerThread2] Starting 'Transformers' subsystem, ID: [Transformers, default] 
11:39:44,383 INFO [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [indexTrackerThread2] Startup of 'Transformers' subsystem, ID: [Transformers, default] complete

I left Alfresco for 12h to do the re-index. But even after 12h neither 10% is done of Lucene indexes. The content store is 177GB larger and on the test server I did re-index in 2h max.

Does anybody has idea why this happening and how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: There's really not very much to go on in your log. Is there anything else? If not, what debug setting did you use?

Answer (score 1):

You may also refer to this Alfresco support article - [How to disable or completely remove Solr, and enable lucne](https://myalfresco.force.com/support/articles/en_US/Technical_Article/How-to-disable-or-completely-remove-Solr-and-enable-lucene)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with 'some' instances.

BTW: you've got Enterprise for **** sake, so this is typically an issue the Alfresco Support can answer.

Instead starting with indexes, try starting with search indexing subsystem as NOINDEX instead of Lusene or Solr.
If this doesn't work, then copy your 4.1. indexes to the 4.2 Alfresco and set index recovery mode to NONE.

When Alfresco eventually starts, open the Enterprise admin console and set the index recovery mode to FULL and save. You'll see that Alfresco will do a full reindex in runtime and it won't have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue, apparently it was caused by a PdfBox bug that has been fixed in 4.2.3 enterprise release